# Tengo problemas al enviar trama ASMT a cobas c111 con python 3

Tags: python-3.x, interface

tengo un problema espero me puedan ayudar, actualmente estoy realizando un script en python para el equipo medico cobas c111 de roche, tengo mayor parte de las funciones ya trabajando, pero mi problema es al momento de scanear el codigo de barras de la muestra y jutsmante cuando quiero enviar los examenes a realizar como un respuesta en ASMT, el punto  es que siempre obtengo una respues NAK.

```
b'\x021H|\\^&|||c111^Roche^c111^4.1.0.1309^1^10774|||||cobas c 111|TSDWN^REPLY|P|1|20211015104647\r\x0304\r\n'
```

desde que que trato de enviar la cabecera tengo ese problema por lo que puedo deducir que el problema es la forma en la que envío la trama, pese a que trato hacerlo como especifica el manual, tal vez alguien que haya trabajado en el tema.

en este link esta el manual con el que estado trabajando

https://manualzz.com/doc/o/13w88t/roche-cobas-c111-manual--host

cualquier duda estoy pendiente

Comment: ¿Cual script? El manual que mencionas no se puede descargar, sólo leer on line.

Comment: justamente es el que encontré, dale como le vas a imprimir y te deja descargar